# jQuery popup needed

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I need to display a popup window when a user clicks a hyperlink on a page.  The popup  needs to display an ASP.NET gridview control, so I may need a little AJAX so I can query the server for datasource depending on which hyperlink the user clicks.

Does something in the jQuery API pretty much fit my needs?  Or, a good plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery UI you have the window plugin. Check the examples [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: This looks promising. But, how do I reference the CSS? The example includes a link to ../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css, but when I go there to download it, there's @imports and then those have more @imports. There's gotto be an easy way to link the style...

Comment: It's really easy. You tipically download a theme, and just reference one file. For example, assuming you download the theme "Smoothness", it has a folder with lots of files. You'll add a simple css reference to:  ~/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" (mind the version)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jQuery would be perfect   .

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI may fit the bill but also check out http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html if you need some fancier effects.